# Firestore: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm currently trying to upgrade my firebase code from version 8 to 9. However, I've encountered this error when I'm trying to get data from the database. It seems that **await** is causing the problem and I'm still pretty new in async.

```
function checkDatabaseData() {
    const uid = localStorage.getItem("uid");
    const docRef = doc(db, "userAdminCreds", uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("Document Data:", docSnap.data());
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("No data");
      return false;
    }
  }

checkDatabaseData();
```

The HTML script tag

```
<script type="module" defer src="js/firebase-firestore-dashboard.js"></script>
```

This is just the same from the firebase guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#web-version-9_1

Comment: Does the <script> have the `type="module"` attribute?

Comment: Yes it has the type="module" attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `await` word you need to have `async` word before `function` word.

```js
async function checkDatabaseData() {
    // ...
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: I've done this but the Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: db is not defined was returned

Comment: @SandrenTroyMilante Guess what next you have to do then if Reference Error: db is not defined.